# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/' defined in ServletContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, zk

Hi im working with the latest version of Spring MVC  and webflow 2.4 and i followed all the steps in order to make it work but i keep getting this error...

Can someone help me?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '/' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/zkSpring-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowExecutor' while setting bean property 'flowExecutor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowRegistry' while setting bean property 'flowDefinitionLocator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0' while setting bean property 'flowBuilderServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0' while setting bean property 'viewFactoryCreator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:642)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowExecutor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'flowRegistry' while setting bean property 'flowDefinitionLocator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0' while setting bean property 'flowBuilderServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0' while setting bean property 'viewFactoryCreator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0' while setting bean property 'flowBuilderServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0' while setting bean property 'viewFactoryCreator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0' while setting bean property 'viewFactoryCreator'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:975)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.FlowResourceFlowViewResolver.<clinit>(FlowResourceFlowViewResolver.java:38)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator.<init>(MvcViewFactoryCreator.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 76 more
```

Here is my zkSpring-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".zul"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Imports the configurations of the different infrastructure systems of the application -->
    <import resource="zkSpring-webflow-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

and my zkSpring-webflow-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

    <bean name="/*" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor"></webflow:flow-executor>

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-location path="/WEB-INF/flows/zkSpring-flow.xml"></webflow:flow-location>
    </webflow:flow-registry>
</beans>
```

Comment: Here's a secret that should help reading these godawful stack traces  - ignore everything after `; nested exception is` in each line. The nested exception is included beneath the exception in the `Caused by:` line. This should save you from a lot of pointless horizontal scrolling back and forth.

Comment: Now what would be really helpful would be if ANYWHERE in the stack trace they actually told you which lines you need to look at. As far as I can tell, these stack traces never actually tell you which line of which file is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause of the exception is "nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;)Z"

It seems to be an incompatible version problem.

Please check all spring framework artifacts' version.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue with Web Flow and Spring 4.0, you need to build with a snapshot build of Web Flow i.e  2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

See [SWF-1600](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1600) and [change details on Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow/commit/853372e54002b83c34d1e91d514ad1a99c541941)

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4.2.4 Release works well with 2.4.2 Release of webflow and dependency of tiles 2.2.2 (tiles-extras, tiles-jsp, tiles-servlet)

```
<webflow-config:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <webflow-config:flow-location path="sales-flow.xml" id="message" />
</webflow-config:flow-registry>

<webflow-config:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />

<bean id="flowHandlerAdaptor"
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="flowHandlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
```